# Click back button to go to previous activity

Tags: android, back-button

Im engineer student developing mini android project.
I have two layouts 1) adding items 2) display items added.
Now i want to add back button where i want to move to previous layout(layout where user adds items) without change(whatever user added items should be shown the same, selected number should not be set to number 0 . Ex: item1 selected 2times item2 selected 3times, so when i click back button it must show the same should not reset to 0). Previous layout must not get refreshed

Comment: It is generally the first lesson of the Android Developer Journey... I suggest you to read some guides : https://developer.android.com/guide

Comment: What are you use Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Activity @HardikTalaviya

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

Android activities are stored in the activity stack so you can go back to a previous activity by opening the new activity from another activity with startActivity or startActivityForResult. In that case you can just call the finishActivity() function from your code and it'll take you back to the previous activity.